# what is issue with my room brick wall? How can i solve it?

Tags: civil-engineering, deformation, retaining-wall, home-improvement, maintenance

I have seen a sort disformation on wall of my room I have attached snapshot of both inside view(from inside room) and out side view(that is out of room)

**inside view is below**
[image]

**out side view is below**
[image]

Comment: I think Freds answer is correct anyway, but maybe you can tell us if both pics are taken at about the same height?

Comment: yes,but not exactly,i have taken both photos through my mobile camera, so in outside view ,my distance from wall when i took snap was greater as compared to that distance when i took snap inside and also i tilted my mobie in bit downward postion before taking snap of inside view

Comment: because inside view is basically behind a bed so i had to tilt my mobile bit downward to take snap

Answer (score 5):

The wall is experiencing [rising damp](https://www.diydoctor.org.uk/projects/rising-damp.htm).

Basically, moisture in the soil is being absorbed by the wall and traveling up the wall. This can become more prevalent during wet periods and subside during dry periods.

The photograph of the outside of the wall appears to show a of line salt crystallizing towards the top of the affected zone. This is not unusual as the rising ground water brings any salt that is within the ground into the wall. As the moisture in the wall evaporates, salt crystallizes on the wall. Over time this can damage the wall. If the wall is made of bricks, it can cause the bricks to crumble.

During construction of the wall, a damp course should have been incorporated into the wall. This is a waterproof layer which prevents ground moisture from rising into the wall above the damp course.

Comment: "Basically, moisture in the soil is being absorbed by the wall and traveling up the wall"   
                                                                                                                                    from where that moisture could came? As underground water level is very low and not near surface of ground

Comment: The water absorbs by the wall is from near surface ground water (a high water table). It is not from ponds if surface water.